# Manipulating csv data to plot a 3D surface

Tags: r, csv

I'm sure this has been asked before. If you can find a good link I'll happily delete the question but I'm not having any luck with Google.
I have a CSV file named "myData.csv", i can read the data in that file from R

```
myData <- read.csv (fil.choose(), header=T)
```

But how can i draw any 3 D plot from the data that i have already read using R
i don't want to rewrite the data again in R, i just need to manipulate myData

myData.csv

```
x    y    value
0    0    4.35
0    1    4.23
0    2    4.24
1    0    4.34
1    1    4.23
1    2    4.22
2    0    4.34
2    1    4.22
2    2    4.22
```

Comment: Please clarify `i just need to manipulate myData`...

Comment: @zx8754 i meant since i read the data from myData.csv i want to plot a 3 D histogram using the table above

Comment: Do you want to make some random 3D plot, using `myData`?

Comment: @zx8754
I am a beginner, it's my first time using R
I want to plot at first any random graph just to make sure that it works .
But then the plot that i will need is a 3 D histogram
Hence, i'd be more than happy if you can help me with that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a 3D histogram with R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684294/creating-a-3d-histogram-with-r)

Comment: @BurakArslan
It's not the same issue i think, because i want to use a ready data in a csv file not writing data at real time 
it is quite different isnt it ?

Comment: Knowing you got the data from csv doesn't change the answer. However, a surface plot (from your title) is not the same as a histogram plot (from your comment). The relevant dupe for the former is probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295737/3d-surface-plot-in-r