# Side by Side histograms in the Same Graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

This should actually be really simple but I'm having a really hard time finding a solution to this problem.

I have two very simple numeric vectors in R. I am simply trying to plot a histogram with them. However I would like them to be on the same graph. The tricky part is R overlaps these two histograms by default. I would like the bins to be simply side by side so I can get a better visual representation of the data.

Basically this is what I want to do

[image]

I am fairly new to R and statistical computing languages in general so I would appreciate it if you would answer my frustrating problem.

Answer (score 18):

The example comes from using the `plotrix`package. Code was found [here](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Multiple_histogram_82). You will first need to install that package before you can access the `multihist` function:

```
#install.packages("plotrix")
require(plotrix)

l <- list(rnorm(50),rnorm(50,sd=2),rnorm(50,mean=3))
multhist(l)
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Here is the ggplot version of this graph.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 2),
                 y = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 2),
                 z = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 10))



ggplot(melt(df), aes(value, fill = variable)) + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: This another way to do it, but it's not exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Jiber You are right, thanks. But the OP said "I would like the bins to be simply side by side so I can get a better visual representation of the data" so there's room for proposing similar visualization.

Comment: I think switching to `geom_freqpoly` might be even more effective.